# CakePHP Shell Error Plugin could not be found

Tags: php, cakephp, cron

I wrote a Shell file named SyncVeevaShell.php (which was basically a copy/paste of some Controller functions) in /app/Console/Command which is supposed to be run via a cronjob every 10 minutes but its not working. When I try to manually run the shell via the command "sh cake SyncVeevaShell.php" I get an error saying plugin SyncVeevaShell could not be found. I don't understand why it would mention a plugin since I'm not trying to use one.

SyncVeevaShell.php:

```
<?php

App::uses('AppShell', 'Console/Command');

class SyncVeevaShell extends AppShell {
public $uses = array('Asset', 'VeevaVault');

public function main()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    App::import('Model', 'Segment');
    $Segment = new Segment();
    App::import('Vendor', 'phpVeeva', array('file' => 'veeva' . DS . 'veeva.php'));
    $veeva = new phpVeeva();
    $veevaList = $veeva->getDocList();

    $this->remove_veeva_asset($veevaList);

    $i = 0;
    while ($i < count($veevaList))
    {
        $obj = $veevaList[$i];
        $filename = $obj->{$veeva::LIST_VALUES}[8];
        $major_ver = $obj->{$veeva::LIST_VALUES}[6];
        $minor_ver = $obj->{$veeva::LIST_VALUES}[7];

        $result = $this->Asset->VeevaVault->find('count', array(
                                        'conditions' => array(
                                            'VeevaVault.title' => $filename,
                                        )
                                    ));                         
        if ($result == 0) {

            $id = $obj->{$veeva::LIST_VALUES}[0]; //get document ID
            $info = $veeva->getInfo($id);
            $ext = $veeva->extensions[$info['format__v']];
            $size = $info['size__v'];
            $mime = $info['format__v'];
            $image = 0;
            if (strpos($mime, 'image') !== false) {
                $image = 1;
            }
            $product = $info['product__v'][0];
            $brand = $Segment->getVeevaBrand($product);
            $message_description = $info['approved_content_description__c'];
            $message_title = $info['title__v'];
            $message_expire = $info['expiration_date__vs'] . ' 12:00:00';
            $message_status = $info['status__v'];
            $url = 'https://frx.veevavault.com/api/v7.0/objects/documents/' . $id . '/file';

            $this->create_veeva_asset($id, $filename, $ext, $size, $mime, $image, $brand, $message_description, $message_title, $message_expire, $message_status, $url, $major_ver, $minor_ver);
        }
        else {

            $result = $this->Asset->VeevaVault->find('count', array(
                                        'conditions' => array(
                                            'VeevaVault.title' => $filename,
                                            'VeevaVault.major_ver' => $major_ver,
                                            'VeevaVault.minor_ver' => $minor_ver
                                        )
                                    ));
            if ($result == 0) {

                $id = $obj->{$veeva::LIST_VALUES}[0];
                $info = $veeva->getInfo($id);
                $ext = $veeva->extensions[$info['format__v']];
                $size = $info['size__v'];
                $mime = $info['format__v'];
                $image = 0;
                if (strpos($mime, 'image') !== false) {
                    $image = 1;
                }
                $product = $info['product__v'][0];
                $brand = $Segment->getVeevaBrand($product);
                $message_description = $info['approved_content_description__c'];
                $message_title = $info['title__v'];
                $message_expire = $info['expiration_date__vs'] . ' 12:00:00';
                $message_status = $info['status__v'];
                $url = 'https://frx.veevavault.com/api/v7.0/objects/documents/' . $id . '/file';

                $this->update_veeva_asset($id, $filename, $ext, $size, $mime, $image, $brand, $message_description, $message_title, $message_expire, $message_status, $url, $major_ver, $minor_ver);
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
}

public function remove_veeva_asset($remoteVeevaList)
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    App::import('Vendor', 'phpVeeva', array('file' => 'veeva' . DS . 'veeva.php'));
    $veeva = new phpVeeva();

    if (!empty($remoteVeevaList)) {

        $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < count($remoteVeevaList))
        {
            $obj = $remoteVeevaList[$i];
            $filename = $obj->{$veeva::LIST_VALUES}[8];
            $remoteVeevaFilenames[] = $filename;
            $i++;
        }

        $localVeevaList = array();
        $query = $this->Asset->VeevaVault->find('all');
        foreach($query as $veeva) {
            $localVeevaList[] = $veeva['VeevaVault'];
        }

        if (!empty($localVeevaList)) {
            foreach($localVeevaList as $localVeeva) {
                if (in_array($localVeeva['title'], $remoteVeevaFilenames) == false) {

                    $id = $localVeeva['id'];
                    $asset_id = $localVeeva['asset_id'];

                    $sql = "DELETE FROM veeva_vaults WHERE id LIKE '" . $id . "'";
                    $db->rawQuery($sql);

                    $sql = "DELETE FROM assets WHERE id LIKE '" . $asset_id . "'";
                    $db->rawQuery($sql);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public function create_veeva_asset($veeva_id, $filename, $ext, $size, $mime, $image, $brand, $message_description, $message_title, $message_expire, $message_status, $url, $major_ver, $minor_ver)
{
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $uuid = String::uuid();
    $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO assets (id, user_id, original_name, name, ext, size, mime_type, is_image, created, modified, is_veeva, message_title, message_description, brand, status, expire_date) VALUES ('" . $uuid . "', null, '" . mysql_real_escape_string($filename) . "', '" . $uuid . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($ext) . "', " . mysql_real_escape_string($size) . ", '" . mysql_real_escape_string($mime) . "', " . mysql_real_escape_string($image) . ", now(), now(), 1, '" . mysql_real_escape_string($message_title) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($message_description) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($brand) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($message_status) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($message_expire) . "')";
    $db->rawQuery($sql);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO veeva_vaults (id, asset_id, veeva_id, title, description, url, created, size, major_ver, minor_ver, ext) VALUES ('" . String::uuid() . "', '" . $uuid . "', '" . $veeva_id . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($filename) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($message_description) . "', '" . $url . "', now(), " . mysql_real_escape_string($size) . ", '" . mysql_real_escape_string($major_ver) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($minor_ver) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($ext) . "')";
    $db->rawQuery($sql);
}

public function update_veeva_asset($id, $filename, $ext, $size, $mime, $image, $brand, $message_description, $message_title, $message_expire, $message_status, $url, $major_ver, $minor_ver)
{
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');

    $sql = "UPDATE assets SET ext = '," . mysql_real_escape_string($ext) . "', size = " . mysql_real_escape_string($size) . ", mime_type = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($mime) . "', modified = now(), messages_title = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($message_title) . "', message_description = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($message_description) . "', brand = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($brand) . "', status = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($message_status) . "' WHERE original_name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($filename) . "'";
    $db->rawQuery($sql);

    $sql = "UPDATE veeva_vaults SET veeva_id = '" . $id . "', description = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($message_description) . "', url = '" . $url . "', size = " . mysql_real_escape_string($size) . ", major_ver = " . mysql_real_escape_string($major_ver) . ", minor_ver = " . mysql_real_escape_string($minor_ver) . ", ext = " . mysql_real_escape_string($ext) . " WHERE title = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($filename) . "'";
    $db->rawQuery($sql);
}
}
?>
```

cronjob:

```
*/10 * * * * cd /var/www/SalesGuru/content/app/Console/Command; /usr/bin/php -q SyncVeevaShell.php > /dev/null ;
```

Error message:

```
Error: Plugin SyncVeevaShell could not be found.
#0 /var/www/SalesGuru/content/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(364): CakePlugin::path('SyncVeevaShell')
#1 /var/www/SalesGuru/content/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(225): App::pluginPath('SyncVeevaShell')
#2 /var/www/SalesGuru/content/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(542): App::path('Console/Command', 'SyncVeevaShell')
#3 [internal function]: App::load('PhpShell')
#4 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('PhpShell')
#5 /var/www/SalesGuru/content/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(241): class_exists('PhpShell')
#6 /var/www/SalesGuru/content/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(191): ShellDispatcher->_getShell('SyncVeevaShell....')
#7 /var/www/SalesGuru/content/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(69): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#8 /var/www/SalesGuru/content/app/Console/cake.php(33): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#9 {main}
```

I'm fairly new to CakePHP and completely new to Shells and cronjobs.

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using. And use $this->loadModel() instead of those manual model creations.

Comment: Wow, that code is FUGLY and SQL injectable. You said that code is taken from a controller? Congrats, your app is exploitable. 90% of that code should be in a model as well. Read the chapter about MVC of the CakePHP book and follow the best practice: Fat models, skinny controllers. This would allow you to share the code as well instead of violating DRY and copying the same code around. Why aren't you using the CakePHP models at all? And finally, mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated in 5.5.

Comment: Other points aside your SyncVeevaShell functions should be in a model file - not directly in your not-model class. +1 because the question is clear even if the code is .. well not =) (I think some people use downvotes to express their dislike for what you're doing rather than "is it a hard-to-understand/bad question).

Comment: Yea the site is awful, I inherited it from another company and followed their coding methodology because I was new to Cake. I realized how bad it was after there was already alot of development done. When/if I have time I will do some code refactoring. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an exact example of this very same use case [in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html):

In your case:

```
*/10 * * * * cd /var/www/SalesGuru/content/app && Console/cake SyncVeeva > /dev/null
```

You

- navigate into your APP dir
- call `Console/cake [ShellName without suffix] [optional command name]`

[The official documentation](http://book.cakephp.org) should always be your very first stop for information. Then google, then forums like this.

Note that you should be able to silence your shell with `-q` (--quit) param instead of using `> /dev/null`.

Comment: Thank you. For the record I didn't write the cron job, it was another developer. But I should have checked it with the documentation before I assumed it was correct. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

My specific case was simple, yet I've still somehow managed to spend time trying to figure it out.

I created a script under `APP/Console/Command` and was trying to run it from the command line, but it kept giving me the *plugin could not be found* error.

Turns out I forgot to include the *Shell* portion into the file name. For example, if your script is called `ClearCache`, the actual file name should be `ClearCacheShell.php`.

Hope this saves someone else a few minutes of time as this post is the first one that comes up on search results.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `sh cake SyncVeeva`

You do not need to include 'Shell.php' when running the script as a shell